# Recyclerview rows gets shrinked after notifydatasetchanged or after notifyItemChanged(position)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-xml

I have a recyclerview that takes a Arraylist as paramter. And when i am adding an image uri to one the objects variables of the list and then refreshing the recylerview 
using

```
rv.notifydatasetchanged
```

then my code properly adds image to the imageview of the object whose uri variable i set but all the rows gets shrinked

and when i am doing

```
rv.notifyItemChanged(position)
```

then that row gets shrinked. And other remains same. I am not modifying width or height after refresh or notifydatasetchanged, thats why i am confused why its happening.

Here is my recylverview row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="feedbackData"

            type="in.myapp.event_subscriber.models.MyData" />

    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/ll_question"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_question_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:text="@{Integer.toString(feedbackData.questionNumber)}"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_question" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/tv_question"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:text="@{feedbackData.question}"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_question_number"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_answer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke_rectangle_grey"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:hint="Write you answer here..."
            android:lines="4"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="@{feedbackData.answer.description}"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ll_question" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_action_attachment"
            goneUnless="@{feedbackData.imageUri==null}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/et_answer">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_attachment" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:text="Add attachment"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_attached_image"
            attachImage="@{feedbackData.imageUri}"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_image_attached_text"
            goneUnless="@{feedbackData.imageUri!=null}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Image Attached Successfully"
            android:textColor="@color/medium_aqua_marine"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:background="@color/grey" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

[image: Before adding image to row]

[image: After adding image to row]

The first image shows my defualt recyclerview, but as soon as i add an image uri from my local storage to the list variable and then call notifydatasetchanged or notifyItemChanged(position), the thing in second image happens. Everything shrinks, even the textviews and divider and everything shrinks.

Code for my recylerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_event_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="Technical corridor"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_event_name" />




    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_subscriber_feedback"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_submit"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider"
        tools:listitem="@layout/row_feedback" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the imageview on which i was setting image and the textview which was only visible after image is set inside one more linearlayout worked. Now its not shrinking. Maybe now only that linearlayout is shrinking upto the width of imageview. I Dont know why this is happening. But atleast this worked and can be used for now.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            goneUnless="@{feedbackData.imageUri!=null}"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_attached_image"
                attachImage="@{feedbackData.imageUri}"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_image_attached_text"
                goneUnless="@{feedbackData.imageUri!=null}"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Image Attached Successfully"
                android:textColor="@color/medium_aqua_marine"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give some hints, might be because recyclerView recalculates views:

**1) for your recycler view `setHasFixedSize(true)`**

**2) set a `LinearLayoutManager` to your recyclerView**

**3) keep using `notifyDataSetChanged(`)**

**4) let your recyclerview be `match_parent` both width and height**

See what happens.

Comment: I already have linearlayout manager. And i am using notifydataSetchanged only. I cannot use match parent on height because i need my recylerview between two views, if you see there is a submit button and one more text on top. So thats why i am using constraint layout there. I am adding my recylerview layout also in question wait.

Comment: And hey i also used constraint layout before in the single row/item layout. Things became even more worse. Then when i was uploading image everything was getting here and there. Even though i had perfect constraint with each other and parent, but still.

Comment: did you set has fixed size to true?

Comment: yes i just did that. Because that was the only thing  i did not try from what u have suggested, but it did not work.

Comment: does setting height of recyclerView to true solves the issue? I know that you don't want that but try to see what happens.

Comment: yes i also did the same just now, i gave it static height of 400dp. Still this problem happened. That means it has something to do with the row layout or binding or that imageview or idk

Comment: try width and height both 0dp for recyclerview.

Comment: hey i tried this, setting the width of imageview inside that row to match_parent from 200dp. And now it did not shrink. So maybe its because of that imageview.  Now what can i do. My requirement is not to make it match_parent but only around 200dp.

Comment: also i will try to put inside a layout and put that layout to match_parent and will try that way

Comment: adding that imageview and textview inside one more layout worked, now maybe its shrinking only that layout, and maybe earlier it was shrinking the root layout. I still dont know why this is happening. This kind of image upload from local storage inside each row of recylerview i am doing first time.

Comment: Try to use a Linear Layout instead of a ConstrainLayout as root and see what changes.

Comment: you mean in row layout or recylerview layout? in row i already have linear only. Constraint was before so i forgot to remove constraints in example code above.

Comment: I mean use linear layout as root in the recyclerview layout, see what changes.